# Python ::: Catch exception with parameters

Tags: python, exception

As in the following documentation for SSH:
http://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/ssh_exception.html

How can I catch the following exception:

```
except paramiko.ssh_exception.BadAuthenticationType(explanation, types)
  # Do your work here...
```

It is easy to catch normal exceptions (that doesn't have parameters) as follows:

```
except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException as e:
  # Do your work here...
```

Comment: Pretty much *all* exception types take parameters. Even if you *can* raise exceptions without parameters if they don't require them, most exceptions are only useful because they accept details of the problem as parameters…

Answer (score 3):

The parameters are used to *create* the exception; it has already been created by the time you can catch it. All exceptions are caught the same way; the only issue is how you access whatever attributes those parameters may have been used to set.

```
except paramiko.ssh_exception.BadAuthenticationType as exc:
    ...
```